# Commutativity of Multiplying Semi-orthogonal Matrix with Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I encounter the following question when I read the paper "Quadratic Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01025.pdf).

Simply speaking, let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m \geq n$ be a semi-orthogonal matrix, i.e. $X^\top X = I_n$. $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are real symmetric matrix.

I wonder why the following holds: $$X^\top AXB = B X^\top AX.$$
In other word, we can commute the multiplication between $X^\top AX$ and $B$.

I have stuck here for a while. Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The condition implies that $X^TAXB$ is a symmetric matrix. This point of view is more useful to see why this is true given $X$ semi-orthogonal and $A, B$ symmetric.

Comment: It does not hold in general but the paper only claims this under assumption referred to as (9) and then indeed it is easy to derive.

Comment: I wrote a script and found this equality doesn't hold in general. 
Thank you Michal, and Edix. I will check it now.